# ActivityNotFoundException when include Android library

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu-12.04

I have a test project which uses [OI FileManager](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/). I added that project to my test project as an Android library, then I call an Activitity in the library. It shows error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1359): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1359): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.androidcoretest/org.openintents.filemanager.FileManagerActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
E/AndroidRuntime( 1359):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1359):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1359):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1359):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1359):    at com.androidcoretest.FileExplorerTest$1.onClick(FileExplorerTest.java:24)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1359):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1359):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1359):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1359):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1359):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1359):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1359):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1359):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1359):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1359):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1359):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I add full path of that Activity in the Manifest, it generates another error.

```
   <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="org.openintents.filemanager.FileManagerActivity" >    
    </activity>
```

It shows:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidcoretest/org.openintents.filemanager.FileManagerActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.androidcoretest/org.openintents.distribution.EulaActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.androidcoretest/org.openintents.distribution.EulaActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at org.openintents.distribution.EulaOrNewVersion.startForwardActivity(EulaOrNewVersion.java:127)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at org.openintents.distribution.EulaOrNewVersion.showEula(EulaOrNewVersion.java:69)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at org.openintents.distribution.DistributionLibrary.showEulaOrNewVersion(DistributionLibrary.java:53)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at org.openintents.filemanager.FileManagerActivity.onCreate(FileManagerActivity.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1393):    ... 11 more
W/ActivityManager(   59):   Force finishing activity com.androidcoretest/org.openintents.filemanager.FileManagerActivity
```

I would say this is a bug of Eclipse. Eclipse and ADT recently have many bugs on building process: ClassNotFound and ActivityNotFound.

Update:
My code just use one line:

```
            final Intent intent = new Intent(FileExplorerTest.this, FileManagerActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

**Actually I have 3 projects. 2 library projects and 1 test project. Library "OI File Manager" uses Library "OI Distribution", then the test project C uses library "IO File Manager".**

Comment: Show how you're starting the activity. When project is added as android library you don't need to put activity tags in your manifest.

Comment: have you tried android:name=".filemanager.FileManagerActivity" OR android:name=".org.openintents.filemanager.FileManagerActivity" the dot(.)

Comment: I tried everything. Cleanup, exclude, restart, include, restart. Nothing changes. If you have time, I give you my teamviewer. Very bored with it. :(

Comment: `final Intent intent = new Intent(FileExplorerTest.this, org.openintents.filemanager.FileManagerActivity.class);` Have you tried this also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you are linking the OI FileManager projects as a library rather than external jar. go to Project properties > Android > Library, then click add library.

Then as you are doing define the activity in your project manifest (however with ADT 20 i think this is automatic)

```
<activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="org.openintents.filemanager.FileManagerActivity" >    
    </activity>
```

Comment: of course, the right way is add it as an Android library. I don't use jar file.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it can't find `com.androidcoretest/org.openintents.distribution.EulaActivity` not the `FileManager` activity. Do you have that `EulaActivity` in the manifest?

See in your log:

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find
>   explicit activity class
>   {com.androidcoretest/org.openintents.distribution.EulaActivity}; have
>   you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?